# Ideal workflow for Git repository for software project and companion server code?

Tags: ios, git, version-control, nginx, webserver

I use Git to manage the source code for my (iOS) project, which I've been doing now for a while which works great. However I'm now beginning to add a server-side component, and I'd like to make sure that the server-side code is kept in the same repository, but separated from the main code-- and set up on the web server so that the whole codebase and history won't be accessible. What's an ideal Git workflow to work with codebases that are on two computers, one local and one sitting on a web server? (By the way, I'm using Nginx if that makes any difference in terms of how to set it up for the server configuration to hide Git files and history.)

Comment: Is there any correlation (shared code) between the iOS and server side?

Comment: No shared code directly (different languages - Objective-C vs. PHP), but the code bases will be dependent, i.e. as the server component changes different past versions of the app may no longer work properly. So I'd like to make sure that the server component, as it changes, is in the same set of commits as the iOS app, so that if need be I can rebuild the server based on what a previous version of the app required (e.g. for git bisect).

Comment: I don't get what's the question. What you mean by "server-side component" and "server-side code"? Do you want to keep 2 separated independent branches in the same repository? That makes no sense. Do you want to secure the repository? That's not git's job. Do you want to have a "git server"? Just init it as `bare`. I see no big question here and no single problem.

Comment: Checking to see if I understand the question: You've got an iPhone app and now you also want to develop a web service for this app. You would like to keep the source code for the new web service in the same Git repository as the code for the iPhone app, but in a separate directory, so that the iPhone app and the web services can be versioned together. (And you've got some kind of web server that sits on top of your Git repository, which is running on Nginx on some server). You're just wondering how to best structure your project (directory structure) in one Git repository?

Comment: Leif -- exactly. How to structure the project, and to set up the git instance on the server so that changes are pushed effectively. And then the question of local / remote staging sites so I can develop without breaking the current setup.

Answer (score 2):

As to the first question, how to track client and server sides together in a way that the server side is still a standalone project. You could incorporate the server code as a submodule into the client project.

```
~/client$ git submodule add foo@bar:server.git
~/client$ git commit
```

This inserts the server repo, accessible at SSH URL `foo@bar:server.git` into your client project into subdir server. An alternative of submodules are subtree merges.

As to checking out the server code into nginx.
Create a bare repo somewhere on the server, let's say /var/git/server.git, and set up its worktree into /var/www/server/

```
cd /var/git
mkdir server.git && cd server.git
git init --bare
git config --bool core.bare false
git config --path core.worktree /var/www/server/
```

Set up its post-receive hook to check out the worktree to the new HEAD.

```
echo '#!/bin/sh' > hooks/post-receive
echo 'git reset --hard HEAD' >> hooks/post-receive
```

Set up a remote in your development pointing to the above:

```
client/server$ git remote add www root@bar:/var/git/server.git
client/server$ git push www master
```

Or something like that...

Comment: What's the purpose of setting `core.bare false`?

Comment: It's because it actually has a worktree, in spite of looking like a bare repo.